# Problem with JWplayer. Video is missing?

Tags: videos, jwplayer, video-player

Firstly, I am new at using video with wordpress. I have installed the jwplayer plugin and using this bit of code to show the video player on the page.

```
$video_array = explode("\r\n", stripslashes(extra_option('video_links')) );

            foreach($video_array as $vid){
                if (!empty($vid))
                echo jwplayer_tag_callback("[jwplayer config=\"Homepage Player\" file=\"$vid\"]"); 
            }
```

**Note:**

"Homepage Player" is a custom config i made form the jwplayer plugin option page.

**Problem:** You can see the site here http://photographersinsiouxfallssd.com/ There are four video to show. For the first three the player isn't showing and the last one player is showing but you can only hear sound but no video :(

Comment: I guess the sound/no video problem is the format, compression or similar of the video. For the other stuff, I'd guess the player can't be embedded more than once per page.

Comment: @kaiser: The video is in `wmv` format. I will try to convert it to `flv` and try again. I also guess that there is some kinds of conflicting going on with player instances.

Comment: Instances: shure. Format: maybe. Could also be some data added by the converter, etc.

Comment: It looks like the video format wasn't supported. When i upload and add mp4 files. The videos are working. Video plays after whole video completes streaming. Searching on that now. Will update when i find something.

Comment: http://blog.evansamek.com/2011/06/22/jwplayer-internet-explorer-jquery-bug-fix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with jwplayer you need to make sure you-

1. Check the supporting file documentation http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats
2. If you are using anything other than mp4 its fine.
3. If you are tying to play mp4 files and you are having problem with it (video not playing before it fully loaded) you must swap the index of the mp4 files using this app http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/

I think that all you will be need to start with jwplayer.